# Getting Into The Nitty-Gritty of Gmail Meter

Tags: gmail

Backstory: I work at a place where we use Gmail for our business email system. We sell things online, provide a phone number, chat, and email for customer service. We can pull statistics from our phone and chat records, but not email.
This is where Gmail Meter comes into play. We installed it hoping to gain more insight into the statistics of our emails. We did, but some of the numbers seem to be off.
Can anyone explain the backend workings of GMeter a bit in hopes to explain why our numbers appear off?

Also, I looked in the gmail admin panel and the Reports tab only appears to give a high level overview of all accounts, not specific ones, such as Total Mail Usage, User Activity, Total Email Accounts, and Usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'm Ryan from the Gmail Meter team. We understand there are some bugs right now, so not everyone's data is being analyzed properly. It seems some parameters are set up for a couple days' worth, instead of a weeks' worth, of counting.

Feel free to shoot me an email and I'll send you an update when we get it fixed.

Thanks for bringing this to attention!

ryan@shuttlecloud.com

Comment: would love if you update this answer too once it gets fixed :)